# I hope this puzzle motivates you

Tags: lateral-thinking, wordplay, visual, rebus

(I saw a similar question in a newspaper. Changing text to images and adding it here)

Recognize the famous saying / quote / idiom / statement / movie or song title. The answer is in English language.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Finally,

[image] [image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer appears to be:

> Where there's a Will, there's a way.

Why?

> Image assistance from @manshu
>  Prince **Will**iam, **Whey** Protein
>  **Will**iams sisters, Wineglass Bay (rhymes with way)
>  **Will** Smith, Road**way**.

Also, this phrase is:

> Often a phrase used to motivate someone when they are feeling unsure about the possibility of something.

Comment: damn beat me as I was typing.

Comment: Good job, anyhow =D

Comment: Correct answer and good reasoning. My reasoning was slightly different on the same line. **Spoiler alert** [My reasoning](http://pastebin.com/7LCgP4bm)

Answer (score 7):

The saying is

> Where there is a will, there is a way

Comment: Oof, a mere 50 seconds afterwards. +1 for effort from me.